# How to protect route in the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have made authentication, I use express-sessions and passports. so when the user login will save the session on the server. to access the route requires this session. the session that I created I saved it in redux store and when I checked `getInitialProps` there was `redux store` I want to use this as a reference if the user is not logged in, it will redirect to the login page.

**, In this case, the URL has changed but I can't access.**

> 

This page is 't working localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I cant use `'next/router'` because Router only can access on the client.

**_app.js**

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import withReduxStore from '../lib/with-redux-store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import getPageContext from '../lib/getPageContext';
import  '../index.css';

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps(something){
    const { Component, router, ctx } = something;
    const initialState = ctx.reduxStore.getState();

    if(Object.keys(initialState.auths.admin).length === 0){
      ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
        Location: '/login'
      });
      ctx.res.end();
      res.finished = true;
      return {}
    }
    let pageProps = {}
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }
    return { pageProps }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.pageContext = getPageContext();
   
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, reduxStore } = this.props
  
    return (
      <Container>
        <Provider store={reduxStore}>
          <JssProvider
            registry={this.pageContext.sheetsRegistry}
            generateClassName={this.pageContext.generateClassName}
          >
            <MuiThemeProvider
              theme={this.pageContext.theme}
              sheetsManager={this.pageContext.sheetsManager}
            >
              <CssBaseline />
              <Component 
              pageContext={this.pageContext} 
              {...pageProps} />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          </JssProvider>
        </Provider>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default withReduxStore(MyApp)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The error “too many redirects” means that the website keeps being
> redirected between different addresses in a way that will never
> complete. Often this is the result of competing redirects, one trying
> to force HTTPS (SSL) and another redirecting back to HTTP (non-SSL),
> or between www and non-www forms of the URL.

In this case, the user will be redirected to '/login' in an infinity loop if Object.keys(initialState.auths.admin).length === 0.